# Ionic Framework How to place a div or buttons below ion-content map

Tags: css, angularjs, android-layout, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project and in a tab I placed a google map following [this](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/) tutorial. Now I want to put some buttons (inside a div?) to trigger some actions over that map. how can achieve that?
I'm really newbie with this framework, I'll appreciate any help.

My index.html

```html
<body>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" animation="nav-title-slide-ios7">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
            <i class="ion-arrow-left-a"></i>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <a class="button" href="#/tab/twitter">
                <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
            </a>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

My maps.html

```html
<ion-view title="Ubicación">
    <ion-content id="maps" scroll="false" data-tap-disabled="true">
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add your map into a separate div

```
<ion-view title="Ubicación">
    <ion-content>
          <div id="maps" scroll="false" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
          <div class="testHello "> My Button </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And position your items on position fixed

```
.testHello { 
  position : absolute;
  background-color: red;
    width : 100%;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

See updated codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNgRpR

Comment: Hello @aorfevre that was my first attemp but without success. I tried with `<ion-view title="Ubicación">
    <ion-content ng-controller="MyControllerName">
          <div id="maps" scroll="false" data-tap-disabled="true"></div> 
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>` too but doesn't show me any map neither.

Comment: Also, JS console doesn't show any problem, in fact, I can see some logs from my controller.

Comment: add a plunkr or codepen with your case, it'll be much easier to help you

Comment: I forked this pen and I tried to add your code. http://codepen.io/fantasticguille/pen/rVjmXm

Comment: That's just what I need. Thanks!