# How to dynamically change the ion-content position? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got an issue, firstly see the structure

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader">
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content class="has-header has-subheader has-footer">
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

I will put dynamic length of text in the `ion-header-bar`, so it can appear as some wider device shows one line, some other device can be multiple lines. My problem is the `ion-content` afterwards, its position is always fixed according to the ionic css file, the bar class always has 44px height. When the `ion-content` has class `'has-header has-subheader'`, in its css, it just uses `'top:44px;'` or `'top:88px;'` hard coded height.

So my actual question is how to dynamically adjust the ion-content position?

I tried to use `ng-style` with `document.querySelector` to fetch the current height of my subheader, however the value is not real-time binded, which when the header expanded because of too many text into multiple lines, the `document.querySelector` in Angular controller is not updated correctly.

I have seen there is a resize() function in the ionic 2.0 code that can update this, but my code is done in ionic 1.x currently, so I'm looking for a 1.x solution here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this [why don't add separated div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30534695/921082), I think I just figured it out with one stupid simple resolution.

Just remove the `ion-header-bar` in the template, and use a div in ion-content, so I avoided using default header since it is at a fixed height in ionic code. Then I don't have to use any DOM query, all div just happily arranged. Just one problem, `ion-nav-bar` height is still fixed, but that can be adjusted by sass.

```
<ion-content class="has-header  has-footer">
    <div class="myheader>
    </div>
   <div class="other-stuff">
   </div>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer-bar>
</ion-footer-bar>
```